# Java ASM dynamic class inheritance

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

Using ASM 9 on Java11, I am able to generate my Sample Class dynamically, but my current class implements interface MyBeanIface

```
public class Sample implements MYBeanIface
{
    public String SampleId = "";
    
    public Sample() {
        this.super();
    }
    
// other getters/setters 
}
```

I want to know how do i implement all methods from interface using ASM?
Also want to know if there is any way to generate toString() method dynamically?

Thanks

Comment: You do it exactly the same way as with any other method.

Comment: Yes, i tried various ways, but not able to get how do i get "this.super()" as i cannot keep 2nd param of visitMethodInsn empty. if there is any sample that you can suggest it would be helpful

Comment: `this.super();` is not legal Java syntax at all. Given that this construct is in `Sample`’s constructor, you probably mean the `super()` constructor call, but then, you’re asking the wrong question. You asked how to implement interface methods or how to implement `toString()`, but you did not ask how to invoke the super constructor. Not being able to implement a valid constructor would also contradict your initial statement “I am able to generate my Sample Class dynamically”.

Comment: Yes, sorry for confusion. I am able to generate class which implements Interface. And looking for advice on how i can invoke super() from my generated class constructor And also implement all ( @Override ) unimplemented methods of my parent Interface from generated class.

Comment: Where is your code using ASM? Please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and how together with a comprehensive error description it helps you to ask good questions and to get helpful answers. Then simply edit your question to be an MCVE. That works magic around here. Please also note that on SO you ask for help with something you are trying to do, rather than asking others to completely do it fo you. Thank you.

Comment: The `@Override` annotation is not mandatory. You implement or override a method by declaring a method with exactly the same name, parameter types, and return type. Just like in source code. A constructor is a special method named `<init>`. If you don’t know this, you haven’t created a constructor at all. Your constructor must have the name `<init>` and the super constructor has the name `<init>`. Recommended read: [JVMS, §3.8. Working with Class Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.8)

Comment: Hi Holger, Thanks a lot, it helped. i am able to get clarity that i need to add those methods and also was able to achieve @Override with mv.visitAnnotation("Ljava/lang/Override;", true);    I am still very new to ASM so got this issue. if you can suggest any link where i can learn various steps using java samples would be helpful.

Comment: Well, the chapter 3 of the JVMS I already linked covers other Java constructs as well, but I think it’s worth having read [the entire JVMS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/index.html) at least once, even if you’ll forget some details afterwards and are never going to implement the bytecode processing on that low level anyway, but it helps understanding what ASM does and why the API is like it is. There’s also the [`ASMifier` tool](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/util/ASMifier.html#main(java.lang.String%5B%5D)) which can show you how to produce certain code.